# Artrifactory and dependency are not showing in main project external libraries list

Tags: android, artifactory, aar

I am updating my project gradle and AGP to 8.0 , I have updated libraries required to update AGP and gradle. I am getting issue. Please consider below scenario

I have project P1 and P2, P2 having some dependency and artrifactory. P1 including P2 as library(artrifactory) dependency. the all dependency and artrifactory we also want in P1 from P2.

But unfortunately when upgrade AGP to 8.0 in both we are not able to find all these library and dependency in P1. Note P2 itself added in P1 but all libraries added under P2 is not adding in P1.